# Is there a way to customize API Platform Admin screens without writing pages and components from scratch?

Tags: react-admin, api-platform.com, symfony5

Does the lack of decorator support prevent this?  I'm hoping to customize certain fields with the prebuilt pages (e.g. instead of an IRI for a subresource field, I want to provide a composite : <resource_description> inside of a chip).

It appears by building my own App.js and components, it is fully customizable, but we also lose all of the prebuilt resources.

I can't seem to find any documentation on simply enhancing the existing prebuilt codebase rather than recreating each show screen, edit screen, list screen, etc. by hand.

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I can't find anything (2 years later)